# How to retrieve DATETIME together with milliseconds

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm doing:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (d DATETIME);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES('2013-10-09 10:58:43.159');
SELECT d FROM foo;
```

and getting

```
2013-10-09 10:58:43
```

How can I get `DATETIME` back together with milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL 5.6.4 and above](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) supports that. Use

```
CREATE TABLE foo (d DATETIME(6));
```